# High pass filter simulation involving loop outside the circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, filter, speakers

I am trying to model a tweeter filter circuit from GR Research's X-CS Encore loudspeakers, more specifically get the transfer function Vo/Vi. I have included an example of how I did it for the woofer circuit. [image: woofer circuit] The circuit diagram for the tweeters is below and that is where the difficulty is. The part that I am having problems with is the final loop in the tweeter circuit that connects to the Vo output (highlighted in the drawing).

[image: tweeter circuit]

I don't know how to model the current going through that section. In my sketches, Vo is the speaker output and Vi is the amplifier source. I come from a mechanical background so while I have taken EE courses involving AC circuits it has never been this complicated. Any help or pointers on where I can learn how to model this circuit would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to know? The transfer function between vi and vo? It’s not clear. 
Also, you need the electrical model for the tweeter in your schematic.

Comment: Seth, without a load that branch current is zero.

Comment: @user69795 Yes I am trying to get the transfer function Vo/Vi. I have edited the post to include how I was able to get the transfer function for the woofers although the circuit is very simle compared to the one for the tweeters.

Comment: Any analysis must include both the source and load impedance models. Otherwise there's nothing to analyze really. Open-load, ideal-voltage-source analysis sure can be performed, but is rather pointless, since the circuit won't ever behave that way in real use. Unless you like to run your speaker filters without speakers attached.

Comment: Also remember that a speaker is an electro-acoustic-mechanical transducer. It reflects the mechanical and acoustic impedance back into the electrical domain. It is an "inductor" only if the former with the coil is mechanically disconnected. As soon as the coil is placed between the poles and is mechanically coupled to the speaker elements, the speaker's mechanical response is reflected back to electrical domain. Add air to the mix, and the speaker's acoustic response is also reflected back to electrical domain. Some approximation of the speaker's electroacoustic model is needed.

Comment: There are approximate electroacoustic models of speakers of various sizes and designs that could get you started. For best results you'd need to measure the speaker on an audio network analyzer, in its enclosure, with all the baffles and other elements in place, in an anechoic chamber. But even measuring it "out in the backyard" is better than measuring it in a room. Especially for subwoofers, the room is part of the acoustic circuit, and will gladly pollute the measurements.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I was performing this analysis to get the Bode diagram for the circuit. From the example I sent with the woofer, I was able to see the cut-off frequency, the degree of attenuation after the cut-off, and the phase of the system. Is there something I am doing incorrectly? When I plotted the transfer function for the woofer I found it looked correct.